# SVN: Commit faiedl while adding/committing index.php to any folder under my repo

Tags: svn, mod-dav-svn

I can add/commit any file/folder to repo but index.php . When I add/commit index.php to any folder under my repo it gives error as below:

```
Command  Commit
Adding   D:\svn\projects\myrepo\index.php
Error    Commit failed (details follow):
Error    Repository moved permanently to
Error    'http://mydomain.com/repos/myrepo/!svn/wrk/RANDOM-HASH/';
Error    please relocate
Error    Repository moved permanently to 'http://mydomain.com/repos/myrepo/'; please relocate
Finished!
```

Repo: under : /var/www/svn/myrepo
url : http://mydomain.com/repos/myrepo
svm mod_dav_svn on Red hat linux with plesk
committing/adding through windows tortoisesvn

I could not find any clue why is it. I have same configrations on my local centos test server for svn and i can commit anything there including index.php.

What can be possible reason?

Comment: Even If i create new index.php in any subfolder and try to add/commit it gives same error. but not for any other file/folder.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the index.php file is still opened in the browser? Sometimes, in certain files, it causes problems. Try closing the browser, then commit.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the bug. Actually I was removing index.php from my url on root of the main domain. ie i was removing index.php by .htaccess and redirecting permanently all domain.com/index.php to domain.com.

Solution was to create a virtual host or subdomain on the site and now i have repos on svn.domain.com/repos and now it works fine for everything since it does not take rule to remove index.php from url from main domain.com but have its own subdomain.